# Redefining the base class at runtime

Tags: c#, .net

Assembly A contains a reference to Assembly B. Assembly A subclasses a class - Class1 - in Assembly B. Assembly C also contains the same base class - Class1. Different implementations and possibly different virtual methods overridden as Class1 also subclasses something. For a minute let's assume I am mad and want to swap out the base class implementation at runtime, replacing what is referenced in Assembly A.

I have investigated [assembly redirection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19(v=vs.110).aspx) which failed because Assembly B is signed and Assembly C is not signed.

I cannot decompile the code and merge the assemblies because there are too many issues to resolve, such as *not* having definitions of all the classes easily discoverable. I cannot use the [CSharpCodeProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.csharp.csharpcodeprovider(v=vs.110).aspx) class due to needing to subclass and would need to decompile. Reflection.Emit is too complicated and I would need to decompile.

An option is to take copies of the subclass and do the dynamic compilation depending on some switch, adding whichever reference in code and typing the result as dynamic. The subclass then lives in a dynamic object but due to interaction with another system I have this horrible feeling it needs to be available at compile time or at least an earlier point. The code is called into by another system, which loads the overridden assemblies probably using Assembly.Load at startup or some other arbitrary point.

Dynamically loading the assemblies using Assembly.Load raises various issues, can you even replace the base class using reflection this way?

Does anybody know of a feasible solution?

EDIT:
More context - the problem is we have an override of some virtual methods which gets rolled out to thousands of boxes. A few hundred boxes need a different implementation of a base class and currently 2 deployments have to be done to get around this with various scripts being applied. The aim is to have binary identical dlls for all deployments and it would be good to find a way of using config to switch out the implementations as and when required rather than changing dlls over thousands of installations, which requires the software to be restarted potentially disrupting business and creating support issues. A mistake has been made earlier and I can't change the monolithic architecture.

Comment: Rather than saying, "This is the mad idea I have in order to solve my actual problem" it would be more helpful to tell us more about the real problem itself. Dynamically swapping base classes feels like a nasty solution which is likely to be really brittle even if you *can* get it to work. So, what are you really trying to do?

Comment: *Why* do you need a different base class though? That's a very odd requirement - indeed, one I can't remember ever needing before. Could this be handled via composition instead of inheritance, for example? (That's usually my first approach if inheritance is causing difficulties...)

Comment: +1 to composition.  Composition is really your friend here.

Comment: The problem is I cannot recompile the base class, it is third party code and my efforts at decompiling and recompiling has run into too many problems

Comment: @JonSkeet A third party system consumes the assembly and relies on the assembly overriding its virtual methods to work. What I need is 2 versions of the base class from the vendor to work in one executable to avoid multiple deployments

Comment: So the problem is that your have all of your code descending from a third party base class.  It seems like that is what you need to change.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is don't subclass. The `is-a` dependency is by definition static and should stay as such. What you want to achieve is a good candidate for separating the interface from the implementation through an `interface` and down-grading the dependency to `has-a`. Then you can use the [delegation pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern#C.23_example) to get things done.

This is a quick example of [constructor injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection#Constructor_injection) which is a special case of [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection).

```
interface IAnimal
{
    int DoSomething();
}

class Bobcat implements IAnimal
{
    private IAnimal _a;

    public Bobcat(IAnimal a) // inject the dependency through the constructor
    {
        this._a = a;
    }

    public int DoSomething() // implement IAnimal
    {
        return _a.DoSomething(); // delegate to _a
    }
}
```

The advantage of *constructor injection* is that you are guaranteed to have an `IAnimal` implementation. You can now add a method for [setter injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection#Setter_injection):

```
public SetAnimal(IAnimal a)
{
    this._a = a; // hot-swap the IAnimal implementation
}
```

You can now set the implementation on construction (at runtime) and even hot-swap it during execution. If you share a single `a` instance across all `Bobcat` instances you can obtain additional features.

The point of all of this is to replace the static `is-a` dependency with a dynamic `has-a` dependency, which still yields instances that behave exactly the same (that is, have methods of the *other* class). Here's more about the [delegation pattern](http://best-practice-software-engineering.ifs.tuwien.ac.at/patterns/delegation.html).

Comment: I'm sorry this a great suggestion but I think I need the inheritance to happen because another system - I can't change the code - consumes the assemblies that do the overriding and it calls the updated code only because of inheritance. The external system provides the dlls which contain virtual methods, we can override the implementation by overriding in a different assembly and then using config to tell the system to look for the new implementations.

Comment: The thing is I can't just not change the code, I can't change the code in 2 assemblies one of which needs to be loaded based on a condition i.e which part of the world the code is running in

Comment: I admit my solution is architectural and requires a redesign and implementation of the code.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what your issue is with @pid's solution is that it doesn't work with `Activator.CreateInstance`.

The solution is to do the injection (if you can call it that) internally in the constructor.

This isn't a solution I would EVER deploy in a system that I have full control with, and you can also optimise this code by replacing the `Activator.CreateInstance` with some kind of runtime `IL` generation (which would bring about (literally) a few thousand times better performance).

```
public class Foo()
{
    private IImplementFoo _implimentation;
    public Foo()
    {
        var implimentationTypeName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Foo"];
        var implimentationType = GetType(implimentationTypeName);
        _implimentation = (IImplementFoo) Activator.CreateInstance(implimentationType);

    }

    public void Bar()
    {
        _implimentation.Bar();
    }
}
```